# how to create hive table based on non-select query

Tags: impala

In my work with impala, I like to save my `show table stats tablename` to a hive table, I am doing this way but got error message:

```
[r001d01i1p:21000] > create table mystats as
                       > show table stats eq_cmplx_exec_master;
```

error:

> Query: create table mystats as show table stats eq_cmplx_exec_master
>   ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2: show table stats
>   eq_cmplx_exec_master ^ Encountered: SHOW Expected: SELECT, VALUES,
>   WITH
>
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Can anyone help me to sort it out please, thank you very much.

Ideally I want the new table contains two extra columns: ID, tablename

Comment: The error message is explicit: you cannot inject the result of a *metadata* command (such as SHOW) into a table, as *data*. #PasDeBol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, here is what I ended up with and it works perfectly as I want:

```
impala-shell -i host-10-17-101-252:25003 -k -q "show table stats dbo" -d default --quiet -B -c -o table_stats.txt
```